# Theano K Means with Shared Variables and Scan

Tags: clustering, python, k-means, theano

I have a pet project to reproduce some common clustering in theano in order to improve my understanding for future projects. I was wondering if anyone has ever used nested theano scans on shared variables to update k means clusters and each nodes assigned cluster. I have a first attempt (listed below) but it isn't updating the clusters appropriately. I was wondering if this is an error in my code or if theano doesn't like this method of implementation. I think this may be an issue with the tensor.eq function to parse out just the nodes assigned to that cluster. Any help is appreciated. Also, I realize this is not the most efficient implementation of this algorithm, but I'm interested if this will work.

Alternately does anyone have an example of K-Means clustering in theano that doesn't involve kohonen networks.

Original Question here [Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149705/theano-k-means-with-shared-variables-and-scan)

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import cluster, datasets

blobs = datasets.make_blobs(n_samples=100, random_state=8)
DATA = blobs[0]

max_x = max(DATA[:,0])
max_y = max(DATA[:,1])
centroids_x = np.random.randint(0,max_x,3)
centroids_y = np.random.randint(0,max_y,3)
centroid_assignment = np.random.randint(0,3,len(DATA))
centroids = np.c_[centroids_x,centroids_y]

print(centroids)
print(DATA)
plt.title('Pre learning')
plt.plot(DATA[:,0], DATA[:,1], 'o', color='yellow')
plt.show()
x = theano.shared(np.asarray(DATA, dtype=theano.config.floatX),name="x")
i = theano.shared(np.asarray(centroid_assignment, dtype=theano.config.floatX),name="i")
c = theano.shared(np.asarray(centroids, dtype=theano.config.floatX),name="c")
final_c = None

def find_min(data_x, c):
    def update_inner_min(data_c, data_x):
        return (data_c ** 2).sum().sqrt() + (data_x ** 2).sum().sqrt() - 2 * T.dot(data_c,data_x.T)
    dist, _ = theano.scan(fn=update_inner_min, outputs_info=None, sequences=[c], non_sequences=data_x)
    return dist.argmin()
min_indexes, update_min = theano.scan(fn=find_min, outputs_info=None, sequences=[x], non_sequences=c)
def update_c(index,x,i):
    def update_inner_c(data_i,data_x,index):
        if T.eq(data_i,index):
            return data_x
        else:
            return T.zeros_like(data_x,theano.config.floatX)
    summable, _ = theano.scan(fn=update_inner_c, outputs_info=None, sequences=[i,x], non_sequences=[index])
    return summable.mean(axis=0)
new_c, update_c = theano.scan(fn=update_c, outputs_info=None, sequences=[T.arange(0,c.shape[0])], non_sequences=[x,i])
learn = theano.function(inputs=[], updates=[(c,T.cast(new_c,theano.config.floatX)),(i,T.cast(min_indexes,theano.config.floatX))], outputs = [new_c,min_indexes])
for i in range(100):
    final_c, indexes = learn()
plt.title('Post learning')
plt.plot(DATA[:, 0], DATA[:, 1], 'o', color='yellow')
plt.plot(final_c[:, 0], final_c[:, 1], "o", color="red")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Scan loops are highly discouraged in theano, as they are very slow.  Generally, you can always convert your problem into a matrix formulation, and k-means is no exception to that.

Comment: @thc would the code for this be similar to [this](https://github.com/erogol/KLP_KMEANS/blob/master/klp_kmeans.py). Maybe using a different metric for updating as mentioned in the readme.

Comment: Yes, it looks like they managed the update rule as a single dot product and T.sum function.  Generally, a summation can be changed into some sort of dot product-like operation, and double sum can be changed into some sort of matrix multiplication.  You don't need to change your metric, you just need to think about how to index your metric and update functions along the matrix indices, instead of the for loop indices.